# "vagrant up" stalls at "default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled" on Windows 7

Tags: vagrant-windows

When trying vagrant with the following setup:

```
vagrant.exe box add ubuntu/trusty64
```

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

when running:

```
vagrant.exe up
```

It stalls immediately after issuing the command at:

```
"default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled"
```

I also observed that a ruby program of Vagrant took almost a full CPU of 4 on my machine forever.

Do you know what's the cause, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working answer here:
http://www.faqssys.info/vagrant-up-stalls-when-verifying-hyper-v-is-enabled/

Need to have the path for VirtualBox.exe maybe VBoxManage.exe of VirtualBox to PATH environment variable, then `vagrant up` took only about 2 minutes to finish successfully.

Comment: As of 2016/06 VirtualBox 5+ is not supported by Vagrant. Only downgrading to lastest version (4.3) helped.